# How to invoke a main method in a nested object?

Tags: scala

The following code has main methods in objects `A` and `A.B`. I can invoke `A` from the command line. Is there any way to invoke `A.B`?

```
object A {
    def main(args : Array[String]) = ()
    object B {
        def main(args : Array[String]) = ()
    }
}
```

What I think is happeing: Scala compiles object `A` to class `A$` and `A.B` to `A$B$`. Neither of these classes has a static method. Scala creates an *additional* class `A` with a static main method that delegates to `A$.main`. But Scala does not compile an equivalent class for `A.B` because the compiler special-cases top-level classes with main methods.

If the above description is correct then there is *no* way to invoke `A.B` on the command line. Is it? If so is there a reason for this implementation?

Comment: Yes. The reason for that implementation is that nobody needs it :)
If you want to run `B.main`, just move it to top level, or create another object, or make `A.main` run it

Comment: @Dima Is there a reason beyond that nobody needs it? There are lots of things nobody needs. In this case Scala's behavior seems inconsistent. Someone carved out a special case for one set of `objects`. It sounds like there must be a reason for that special case: perhaps a technical issue implementing this functionality more broadly?

Comment: When you don't need something there is usually no reason for it. Do you need an empty soda bottle right now? Why not? ;) Not needing something is _lack_ of reason to have it. There is an obvious reason to have _some_ way to run a scala program from command line. There is no reason to be able to run it in every way one can imagine. It's not a "special case". One top level object, the other one is nested. FWIW, you can't execute nested classes in java either.

Comment: @Dima Okay fair enough, if executing nested objects is seen as an extra, I understand why it isn't implemented. If you post an answer I will accept. BTW you can execute static inner classes in Java.

Comment: Hm, indeed you can ... I didn't know that (25 years java experience) :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as you noticed, `object A { ... }` ends up as a class `A$`, not `A`, it has a `main` method, but it is not static. 
Scala objects are singleton instances, not just classes with a bunch of static methods.

So, to be able to run `scala A` from command line, scalac generates another class `A`, with a static method `main`, that calls `A$.MODULE$.main` ...

This is a special piece of extra logic, needed to comply with jvm's assumptions of how to look for `main` when it starts from command line.

The compiler only does it for top-level objects, that have a `main` method *and* do not have a companion class (because if they did, the name would clash with the generated class).

Why it does not do it for nested classes? I don't think there some sort of a reason specifically preventing it (like the name clash I mentioned above), probably, just because nobody asked for it.

Answer (score 0):

The inner object B is not visible from outside. To invoke its main method, you have to provide an interface in A, for example from its main method, so you can pass the args without further ado:

```
object A {

    def main(args : Array[String]) = {
        println ("outer A.main")
        B.main (args)
    }

    object B {
        def main(args : Array[String]) = {
            println ("inner B.main")
        }
    }
}
```

Invokation:

```
scala -howtorun:object A
outer A.main
inner B.main
```

Test:

```
scala -howtorun:object A.B
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: A.B
```